# journal for mathematics of philosophy/mythology

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-mathematics, philosophy-of-mind, myths

I have been working on research involving the use of mathematical formulas and reasoning in order to philosophical concepts, specifically concepts concerning mythology, the Jungian model of the psyche, genius(in the archaic usage for an individual's unique way of seeing the world instead of the special giftedness of an individual), and process of individuation.

So, basically I am applying mathematics to solve deeply philosophical questions that are becoming increasingly important in our modern world as we struggle to discover who we are and what gifts we have for the world all the while living in a society that sacrifices our need for understanding our Self for the unhealthy obsessions with technology.

I am using mathematical formulae as in Hegel's Dialectic approach to history and competing ideologies, as well as Carl Jung/Joseph Campbell's use of archetypes. It is less of a structuralist's approach and more of a combination of psychoanalysis and humanistic approach. I hope that clarifies in what way am I using math to address mythology.

I am looking for either a journal to publish my research in or directions towards recommending the creation of a new journal and submit my research to it. Would it be better to publish my research in a philosophy journal or a mathematical journal? Does anyone have any suggestions for publication and why they suggest the journal that they do?

Comment: How are you using mathematical formulas in mythology, as in [Lévi-Strauss's structuralism](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0306174)? [Semiotica](https://www.degruyter.com/view/j/semi.1995.105.issue-1-2/semi.1995.105.1-2.69/semi.1995.105.1-2.69.xml) might take something like that. There is also [Jung Journal](https://www.tandfonline.com/toc/ujun20/current). You'll have to be more specific for more.

Comment: I added in the third paragraph, which aims to address your question regarding the use of math language in mythology, as in what psychological method am I using in my mythological analysis.

Comment: But genius in ancient Greece stood for some type of being, which, I believe, meant "initiator" or "the one from whom it begins". I never saw use of "genius" in your sense.

Comment: As I take it, genius in this context still is the "initiator of the Self", but being a type of being or a psychological archetype is not a difference in meaning rather a difference in interpretation and theology. It is like saying post greek contact slavic conception of the gods is different to slavic gods before greek contact. Whereas before, Slavs saw their gods in a more spirit and non-anthromophic context, post-greek contact slavs saw the gods as the greeks did--that is anthromophically.